# The vector I programmed in C++ is returning nothing. It is supposed to return 5 elements

Tags: c++, vector

Hi I am having trouble witht his C++ code, developed with Code Blockers. It implements sense and move of robot( very basic ) , there is vector **p** of probabilites that wil change ofter I apply the sense and move im my main function.

There is a **sense function** and a **move function**  below that basically change my **vector** of probabilities **p** .

I call them in my main fucntion but it does not seem to work it return 5 nan values.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

vector<float> p (5);
vector<string> world (5);
vector<string> measurements (2);
vector<int> motions (2);
float pHit;
float pMiss;
float pExact;
float pOvershoot;
float pUndershoot;
vector<float> sense(vector<float> p, string Z);
vector<float> move(vector<float> p, int U);


int main(){
    vector<float> p = {0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2};
    vector<string> world = {"green", "red", "red", "green", "green"};
    vector<string> measurements = {"red", "green"};
    //string measurements = "red";
    vector<int> motions = {1,1};
    float pHit = 0.6;
    float pMiss = 0.2;
    float pExact = 0.8;
    float p0vershoot = 0.1;
    float pUndershoot = 0.1;

    vector<float> sense(vector<float> p, string Z);
    vector<float> moves(vector<float> p, int U);


    for(int i=0; i<measurements.size(); i++){
        p = sense(p, measurements[i]);
        p = moves(p, motions[i]);
    }

    for(int i=0; i<p.size(); i++){
        cout << p[i] << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}

vector<float> sense(vector<float> p, string Z){
    vector<float> q;
   // q.reserve(p.size());
    for(int i=0; i<p.size(); i++){
        bool hit = (Z == world[i]);
        q.push_back(p[i] * (hit * pHit + (1-hit) * pMiss));
    }

    float s = 0.0;
    for(int i=0; i<q.size(); i++){
        s += q[i];
    }

    for(int i=0; i<q.size(); i++){
        q[i] /= s;
    }

    return q;
}

vector<float> moves(vector<float> p, int U){
    vector<float> q;
   // q.reserve(p.size());
    for(int i=0; i<p.size(); i++){
        float s = pExact * p[(i-U) % p.size()];
        s = s + pOvershoot * p[(i-U-1) % p.size()];
        s = s + pUndershoot * p[(i-U+1) % p.size()];
        q.push_back(s);
    }
    return q;
}
```

Comment: You declare a bunch of local variables in `main`, `float pHit = 0.6;` etc., but then you use uninitialized global variables of similar name inside your other functions

Comment: also `(i-U) % p.size()` gives a negative number if `U > i` and you will read out of bounds of `p`.  (Use `p.at(x)` instead of `p[x]` to help detect this)

Comment: Multiplying by a boolean? That's just weird... "false time 4.2"...

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a free debugging service, and you should show your attempts at debugging the code with a debugger or other simpler methods such as debug print statements. This won't be the only time you end up with a bug in your code, and learning to debug your programs will help you much more than having someone find the bug for you. http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/

Comment: You have global variables and function local variables with the same name. It will be easier for you track down if you remove the global variables. Pass the variables from `main` to other functions as you need them.

Comment: Could you trim down the code, so that we're looking at just the parts that (compile and) exhibit the wrong behavior? Especially those declaration blocks -- how many variables do you really need to replicate the bad result?

Comment: Step 1: Debug and corner down the bug to a few lines of code
Step 2: Post your findings of debugging here

Comment: What is the purpose of this code:  s = pExact * p[(i - U) % p.size()]? Note, that with i == 0 i - U will be -1.

Answer (score 0):

Your code wouldn't compile the way you presented it here. First, you are trying to reference local variables defined in main in other functions.Second, you have a bunch of implicit double to float conversions. If these issues are addressed one way or another, your code appears to work (see the code below).

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

vector<double> p = { 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2 };
vector<string> world = { "green", "red", "red", "green", "green" };
vector<string> measurements = { "red", "green" };

float pHit = 0.6;
float pMiss = 0.2;
float pExact = 0.8;
float pOvershoot = 0.1;
float pUndershoot = 0.1;

int main() {
    //string measurements = "red";
    vector<int> motions = { 1,1 };

    vector<double> sense(vector<double> p, string Z);
    vector<double> moves(vector<double> p, int U);


    for (int i = 0; i<measurements.size(); i++) {
        p = sense(p, measurements[i]);
        p = moves(p, motions[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i<p.size(); i++) {
        cout << p[i] << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}

vector<double> sense(vector<double> p, string Z) {
    vector<double> q;
    // q.reserve(p.size());
    for (int i = 0; i<p.size(); i++) {
        bool hit = (Z == world[i]);
        q.push_back(p[i] * (hit * pHit + (1 - hit) * pMiss));
    }

    float s = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i<q.size(); i++) {
        s += q[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i<q.size(); i++) {
        q[i] /= s;
    }

    return q;
}

vector<double> moves(vector<double> p, int U) {
    vector<double> q;
    // q.reserve(p.size());
    for (int i = 0; i<p.size(); i++) {
        float s = pExact * p[(i - U) % p.size()];
        s = s + pOvershoot * p[(i - U - 1) % p.size()];
        s = s + pUndershoot * p[(i - U + 1) % p.size()];
        q.push_back(s);
    }
    return q;
}
```

Comment: This still has the problem of `p[(i - U) % p.size()];` accessing out of bounds

Comment: Can you be more specific? This is the output I am getting :0.161053 0.148421 0.0810526 0.168421 0.387368 Press any key to continue . . . What output do you get? How do you compile and run this code? On what platform?

Comment: I didn't run it, I noticed a mistake by looking at the code. The code does `p[-1 % 5u]` . (Which actually isn't an out of bounds access but , assuming OP meant it to resolve to `p[4]`, it doesn't do that)

Comment: Well, I did run it - and the output is above. Looking at the code, I do not quite understand the indexing in this part, and there are not a lot of comments. The index computation does seem to be broken. Maybe the author can explain what is he trying to achieve here?

Comment: @VictorHavin the correct answer should be 0.211  0151  0.810526  0.168421 0.387368

Comment: I did some corrections and i got the same results as you. What this code  does is that it simulates the move of a robot